# Intent Service stopping before finishing the task?

Tags: android, service

I have a `IntentService` I am doing some task in another thread in

`onHandleIntent(Intent intent)`

Why is the `IntentService` stopping before performing the operation(task)?

Here is my code:

```
public class SampleIntentService extends IntentService {

    public static final int DOWNLOAD_ERROR = 10;
    public static final int DOWNLOAD_SUCCESS = 11;

    public SampleIntentService() {
        super(SampleIntentService.class.getName());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        final String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
        final ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return downloadFile(url, receiver);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String filePath) {
                super.onPostExecute(filePath);
                bundle.putString("filePath", filePath);
                receiver.send(DOWNLOAD_SUCCESS, bundle);
            }
        };

    }

    private String downloadFile(String url, ResultReceiver receiver) {
        File downloadFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.pathSeparator + "test.png");
        if (downloadFile.exists())
            downloadFile.delete();
        try {
            downloadFile.createNewFile();
            URL downloadURL = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) downloadURL
                    .openConnection();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode != 200)
                throw new Exception("Error in connection");
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(downloadFile);
            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
            int byteCount;
            while ((byteCount = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
            }
            os.close();
            is.close();

            String filePath = downloadFile.getPath();
            return filePath;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            receiver.send(DOWNLOAD_ERROR, Bundle.EMPTY);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Docs:

```
abstract void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
```

> This method is invoked on the worker thread with a request to process.

Since this method is already invoked on **worker thread** you don't need to start  another thread.

If you do that, the `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)` will return and the `IntentService` will think the task is done and it will stop itself.

Source: [`onHandleIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent))

Here is the updated code :

```
public class SampleIntentService extends IntentService {

    public static final int DOWNLOAD_ERROR = 10;
    public static final int DOWNLOAD_SUCCESS = 11;

    public SampleIntentService() {
        super(SampleIntentService.class.getName());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        final String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
        final ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        String filePath = downloadFile(url, receiver);
        bundle.putString("filePath", filePath);
        receiver.send(DOWNLOAD_SUCCESS, bundle);

    }

    private String downloadFile(String url, ResultReceiver receiver) {
        File downloadFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.pathSeparator + "test.png");
        if (downloadFile.exists())
            downloadFile.delete();
        try {
            downloadFile.createNewFile();
            URL downloadURL = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) downloadURL
                    .openConnection();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode != 200)
                throw new Exception("Error in connection");
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(downloadFile);
            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
            int byteCount;
            while ((byteCount = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
            }
            os.close();
            is.close();

            String filePath = downloadFile.getPath();
            return filePath;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            receiver.send(DOWNLOAD_ERROR, Bundle.EMPTY);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: hey this is unreleated to this question. But how did you solve your mainactivity leaked issue with hj.o as GC root? I am having the same issue. Thanks :)


I came across your question from google cache while searching for my issue.